# How to represent 45 degree and 26.565 degree angle in 32 bit binary form?

Tags: verilog, fft, system-verilog, vivado, cordic

I am writing the verilog code for CORDIC (COordinate Rotation DIgital Computer) in xilinx vivado. For that I need 45, 26.565 degree rotation angle in 32-bit binary form. After searching in the internet I got 45 degree angle can be represented as

```
assign z[00] = 'b00100000000000000000000000000000;
```

and 26.565 degree angle can be represented as

```
assign z[01] = 'b00010010111001000000010100011101;
```

Can anybody explain to me how they are representing the 45 degree and 26.565 degree angle in binary form? Is there any formula behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round((45 / 360) * 2 ** 32)` is equal to `'b00100000000000000000000000000000` (exacly your number)

`round((26.565 / 360) * 2 ** 32)` is equal to `'b00010010111001000000001010111011` (almost your number, difference 0.00005 degree)

Formula propably is equal to `(angle / 360) * 2 ** 32`.